# How do I make items run commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a carrots on sticks run commands, but I want different carrots on sticks to have different names and run different commands. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi, I edited your question to make it more clear. Is the info still correct?

Comment: What exactly does, "depending on their item name" mean?

Comment: @Korogue I edited the question back to something similar to the original version. It's still unclear though.

Comment: I have a feeling you might be looking for *right-click detection* with the carrots on sticks, but I'm not sure. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

For running commands if you're holding the item, you can use `as` or `at` the player, and use the `nbt` target selector to check for the `SelectedItem` tag of the player.

```
execute as @a[nbt = {SelectedItem: {id: "minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick", tag: {custom_tag: 1b}}}] at @s run say test
```

Here's a quick rundown:

- `as` changes the executor of the command *as* the entity, meaning you can use `@s` to target the executor's self just after declaring who to execute it as.
- `at` changes the positional context of the command, meaning it will run the command relative to the entity.
- It's not necessary to use both, but it really depends on what you're doing.
- `@a[...]` indicates players, meaning it will only select players.
- `nbt` checks for the entity's NBT, which in this case, we're checking for the player's `SelectedItem` tag
- `{SelectedItem: {id: "minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick", tag: {custom_tag: 1b}}}` refers to the item about to be checked. We'll set the `id` string to `"minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick"` since we'll be checking for that item. As for `tag`, it refers to the item's NBT. In this case, we'll be checking for the `custom_tag: 1b` NBT in the item.

The item in the provided example can be obtained by running this command:

```
give <player> minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick{custom_tag: 1b}
```

Now, if you want to check if a player has interacted with that specific carrot on a stick, you would need a scoreboard with the `minecraft.used:minecraft.carrot_on_a_stick` criterion. As for why, [it's a bug that would be useful in our case.](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-112991)

After creating the objective, you would check if a player has a score in the scoreboard objective, using the `scores` target selector argument. So the whole command would look like this:

```
execute as @a[nbt = {SelectedItem: {id: "minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick", tag: {custom_tag: 1b}}}, scores = {<objective> = 1..}] at @s run say test
```

- `<objective>` being the name of your newly created scoreboard objective.
- `1..` is a range that would check if the player has 1 or more value in the said objective

Afterwards, you would reset the score of the player in the objective by running a `/scoreboard players` command:

```
scoreboard players reset @a[scores = {<objective> = 1..}] <objective>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something on this lines of `/execute at @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:<id>",name:"<name>"}}] run <command>` in order to run the command, replacing anything in <> with the appropriate option. You can run this as many times as you want, changing those 3 selectors, as long as those are in repeating command blocks, either constantly powered or with "always active" enabled.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I forgot to add that, edited it in now

Comment: will `<at/as>` really not throw an error? I've never seen that. I believe it doesn't, and if that's the case please clarify what that even means (are we picking, what do we pick, etc.)

Comment: no, anything in <> should either be entirely replaced or modified to fit one of the options given. I should maybe clear that all up